# React Big Calendar Navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

In my calendar, I made the option to open and close it, but when I close it, and open it again, it is in the month I stopped after closing it, and not in the current month, I want it to open in the current month, I already tried CurrentDate but it keeps opening in the last month I stopped, not the current month.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if your 'open/close' is hiding the calendar rather then adding it/removing it from the DOM, in which case if will retain state. If you add/remove from DOM on open/close, then the control should rerender, as long as your calendar state is not connected to a higher level context.

```js
{open ? <MyCalendar /> : null}
```